# If form value equals a specifc then die

Tags: php, mysql

Before my data is entered into the database using the `$_POST` function I would like to check the name of a field.  If the comment_author_name is equal to a specific name, I would like to quit/die/kill the function.

For example, if the name of the comment author is John on the HTML form, I would like the PHP function to die so that the data does not get entered into the database.

The below code isn't working.  What am I missing?  Is there a better way to do this??

```
<?php
    $val1 = "John";
    if (($row->comment_author_name) == ($val1))
        {
    die("You are not allowed to post!");
        }
?>
```

Comment: Where is `$row` coming from? Are you sure you don't mean `$_POST['comment_author_name']`?

Comment: What $row->comment_author_name does? It just takes $_POST value or something else? Have you tried for other fields?

Comment: You are not programming in LISP so don't use more parentheses than the average LISP programmer. ;) (get rid of the parentheses around `$val1` and `$row->comment_author_name` - and indent your code properly!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
if ($_POST['comment_author_name'] == 'John'){
  die("You are not allowed to post!");
}
```